# Insert form data into database with Php and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, crud

I have some trouble with inserting data into a mysql database using pdo and php. I've tried a lot of things on the internet but nothing seems to work.

This is what I've got that's the closest to working:

The database connection:

```
<?php
    class Database
 {

private static $dbName = 'gildeuitleen' ;
private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
private static $dbUsername = 'root';
private static $dbUserPassword = 'root';

private static $cont  = null;

public function __construct() {
    die('Init function is not allowed');
}

public static function connect()
{

   if ( null == self::$cont )
   {     
    try
    {
      //Connectie maken
      self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      die($e->getMessage()); 
    }
   }
   return self::$cont;
}

public static function disconnect()
{
    self::$cont = null;
}
  }
  ?>
```

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="add.php">
                <input type="text" name="Barcode" placeholder="Barcode" required><br>
                <select name="Product">
                  <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
                  <option value="beamer">Beamer</option>
                </select><br>
                <select name="Vestiging">
                  <option value="venlo">Venlo</option>
                  <option value="Venray">Venray</option>
                  <option value="Roermond">Roermond</option>
                  <option value="Weert">Weert</option>
                </select> <br>
                <input type="text" name="Datumuitgave" placeholder="JJJJ-MM-DD" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="Datumteruggave" placeholder="JJJJ-MM-DD" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="Persoonlijknummer" placeholder="Persoonlijk nummer" required><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen">


            </form>
```

The add.php file:

```
 <?php

        include 'includes/database-inc.php';

        $pdo = Database::connect();

        try{

            $query = "INSERT INTO leningen (Barcode, Product, Vestiging, Datum uitgave, Datum teruggave, Persoonlijk nummer huurder) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);   

            $stmt->execute();

            header('Location: OverzichtProducten.php?succes');
            exit();

            }


        catch(PDOException $exception){

            die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());

    }
    ?>
```

Anyone got any idea what's going wrong here? It sends me back to the page as normal, but adds nothing to the database.

Comment: How should the query know what `VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` is?

Comment: you prepared the query, but you haven't loaded all values in the execution

Comment: You forgot to bind values.

Comment: You shouldn't die in constructor, and as B001 said, you should bind the values on ?. eg. $stmt->execute(array("val1, val2, val3, etc"));

Comment: roytuts.com/rest-api-crud-example-in-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

this will give you your "bobs"

**EDIT**
to test : run this as a separate url ignore the form etc

EG:

save file as bob.php
visit http://myurl.com/bob.php make sure the `includes/database-inc.php` include is "findable" and then post the result

```
<?php

    include 'includes/database-inc.php';

    $pdo = Database::connect();

    try{

        $query = "INSERT INTO leningen ";
        $query += " (`Barcode`, `Product`, `Vestiging`, `Datum uitgave`, `Datum teruggave`, `Persoonlijk nummer huurder`) ";
        $query += "VALUES (:barcode, :product, :vestiging, :datum_uitgave, :datum_teruggave, :persoonlijk_nummer)"; 

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);   

        $stmt->execute(array(
          "barcode" => "Bob",
          "product" => "Bob",
          "vestiging" => "Bob",
          "datum_uitgave" => "Bob",
          "datum_teruggave" => "Bob",
          "persoonlijk_nummer" => "Bob"
        ));

        echo "Success";
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception){
        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception $exception) {
       die('General Error: '.$exception->getMessage());
    }
?>
```

also make `$cont static public` and call $pdo->cont->prepare();

Comment: Still get the same result, sadly :(

Comment: then your problem is not with PDO and there are other issues. EG: can the database can connect using those credentials? I would get rid of the  `header/exit` redirect it causes a lot of mess. see the error message to the screen. ( I digress, but it's much better to `include` the place you go to but you need to design the whole solution around this).

Comment: i've added a `general exception` to the catch to help you

Comment: The database itself can connect, it displays the data correctly on another page. I'm not sure if it also connects to add tho. I'm still new to all of this :p

Comment: where is your `class Database ->prepare method()??`

Comment: Where should that prepare method be?
Sorry again, I don't have any experience with databases

Comment: `self::$cont` is the PDO object. This has a `->prepare()` and a `->execute()` in it, the `Database` object you call `$pdo` isn't actually a `PDO()` it's a container of and `PDO` in `$cont` .. i.e. the `prepare()` reference doesn't itself exist at that level of the object you reference but `$pdo->cont->prepare()` does (if you make it public)

Comment: what I am trying to say is the line `$pdo->prepare()` is illegal unless you make a method is your `class Database` so I suspect it fails before it starts, but since you ONLY CATCH `$PDOExceptions` and not vanilla `$Exceptions` you can't see the error! it's a PHP Exception when you reference a method in a class that doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="add.php">
            <input type="text" name="Barcode" placeholder="Barcode" required><br>
            <select name="Product">
              <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
              <option value="beamer">Beamer</option>
            </select><br>
            <select name="Vestiging">
              <option value="venlo">Venlo</option>
              <option value="Venray">Venray</option>
              <option value="Roermond">Roermond</option>
              <option value="Weert">Weert</option>
            </select> <br>
            <input type="text" name="Datumuitgave" placeholder="JJJJ-MM-DD" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="Datumteruggave" placeholder="JJJJ-MM-DD" required><br>
            <input type="text" name="Persoonlijknummer" placeholder="Persoonlijk nummer" required><br>
            <input type="submit"  value="Toevoegen">


        </form>
```

`The add.php file:`

```
$Barcode= $_POST['Barcode'];    
$Vestiging= $_POST['Vestiging'];    
$Datumuitgave= $_POST['Datumuitgave'];  
$Datumteruggave= $_POST['Datumteruggave'];  
$Persoonlijknummer= $_POST['Persoonlijknummer'];

    include 'includes/database-inc.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();

    try{

        $query = "INSERT INTO leningen (Barcode, Product, Vestiging, Datum uitgave, Datum teruggave, Persoonlijk nummer huurder) VALUES (:Barcode,Vestiging,:Datumuitgave,:Datumteruggave,:Persoonlijknummer)"; 

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);   
        $stmt->bindparam(":Barcode",$Barcode);
        $stmt->bindparam(":Vestiging",$Vestiging);
        $stmt->bindparam(":Datumuitgave",$Datumuitgave);
        $stmt->bindparam(":Datumteruggave",$Datumteruggave);    
        $stmt->bindparam(":Persoonlijknummer",$Persoonlijknummer);
        $stmt->execute();

        header('Location: OverzichtProducten.php?succes');
        exit();

        }


    catch(PDOException $exception){

        die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());

}
?>
```